# OP forgot to follow the answers for a question for which they raised a bounty, but accepted an answer after the bounty expired

Tags: support, bounty, accepted-answer

I answered [a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058614/bus-properties-settings-ignored/72174500#72174500) which had a bounty. Eventually, the bounty period expired, and the OP, who raised the question and started the bounty, forgot to follow this question for some reason.

The OP later came back and accepted my answer, but the bounty had already expired (the OP mentioned they lost track of question & forgot to reward the bounty in the comments section of my answer, but this has now been deleted).

Is there a way to claim a bounty in this scenario?

Comment: *"Is there any way to claim bounty in this scenario?"* Nope. If the OP "feels bad" they would have to create a new bounty (and they would have to "pay" more, due to bountying the question a second time).

Comment: _"I can see no conversation"_ - then, assuming they were there previously, those comments have been deleted by a moderator as being irrelevant to the content of the actual Q&A.

Comment: @jonrsharpe , comments were there until today -- because I checked before posting link of question, those got deleted in last 2 or 3 hours. I am ok to have those removed , but mentioning it in my original question so that new reader knows context of my question.

Answer (score -2):

No, you won't be able to claim the bounty at this point.